# Core Data, NSPredicate, ANY key.path == nil

Tags: core-data, nspredicate

I came up with a solution to this using subquery, but I don't understand why what I was trying to do first didn't work.

Here's my data model. I'm fetching on Advice.

[image]

I can do the following as a predicate:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY conditions.terrain == %@", aTerrainObject];
```

that works fine, and returns any piece of advice where at least one of its conditions has that terrain type.

However, when I try to do this, it fails:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY conditions.terrain == nil"];
```

What I want to do is return any piece of advice where at least one of its conditions doesn't have a terrain type set.

However, the following does work:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(conditions, $x, $x.terrain == nil).@count > 0"];
```

Can anyone explain why, when searching for nil, I can't use the `ANY` syntax?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> Can anyone explain why, when searching for nil, I can't use the ANY syntax?

Yep!  Here's what's going on.

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY conditions.terrain == nil"];
```

First, let's break this up into the appropriate left and right expressions:

```
conditions.terrain
```

This will be evaluated by taking the `SELF` object (an `Advice` instance) and requesting the `valueForKeyPath:@"conditions.terrain"`.  The result of this keypath will be a collection.  You're essentially doing:

```
Advice *a = ...;
NSSet *conditions = [a conditions];
NSSet *terrains = [conditions valueForKey:@"terrain"];
```

So, you have a collection of (potential) `Terrain` instances.  Now, what do we know about collections in Objective-C?  Well for one thing, they cannot contain `nil`.  They can only contain objects.  This means that when it executes the `ANY` portion of the predicate, it's going to iterate through the items in the array and see that none of them are `nil`.

Thus, your predicate is failing.  I tried playing around with some other variations (using `[NSNull null]` instead of `nil`, etc), but none of them seemed to work.

It would therefore appear that your use of a `SUBQUERY` to solve this is about as good as you could get.  I would highly recommend [filing a bug](https://bugreport.apple.com) detailing your expectations and expressing why you think this should work.

Comment: Excellent reply. Thank you for being thorough and precise.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I believe you cannot use `nil` in the query. You should maybe use `NULL` or the format string construct like  `"ANY conditions.terrain == %@", nil`.</strike>

What puzzles me is that your subquery is working...

*The above is not correct, as `NULL`and `NIL`can be used interchangeably.*

Instead, the [NSExpression Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/Reference/NSExpression.html) gives exactly your pattern (with `@count`) as the preferred example.

Did you check that the terrain relationship is optional?