# NSPredicate format to check for null paths

Tags: ios, subquery, nspredicate, null, any

I have the following data model:

Person -(OneToMany)-> Task -(OptionalOneToOne)-> Completion

and I need a predicate to return me the persons without incomplete tasks and another for the opposite. A task is completed if there's a completion entity associated and not completed if that reference is nil.
I was tempted to use `ALL task.completion = nil` and `NONE task.completion = nil` but that's a mistake since the core data framework wraps everything in arrays or sets and they cannot contain a list of nils, so the only way to really solve that is using SUBQUERYs and that's way outside my comfort zone.
Plus, I can't find expressive examples of SUBQUERY inside NSPredicate but I know the answer lies there, if this is trivial for anyone please help me break this deadlock.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `task.completion.count == 0`, maybe? Or, `task.completion[SIZE] == 0`.

Comment: completion is a OneToOne relation it's an object not a collection.

Comment: One to One, you say? `task.completion == nil` would do. Core Data only wraps One to Many or Many to Many relationships with sets. And not arrays.

Comment: Please read the post again. I don't need the list of tasks that are completed I need the list of PERSONS with NO tasks NOT completed or in better english the list of persons with no incomplete tasks.

Comment: The predicates you were tempted to use would work, try them.

Comment: Is this the same problem as in your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26188309/nspredicate-does-not-work-as-expected-for-all-relationship-innerrelationship ?

Comment: I tried them and they didn't work, I explain why in the post, you can read about it in more detail here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13193872/core-data-nspredicate-any-key-path-nil Check the answer by Dave DeLong

Comment: @MartinR it kind of is an update to it yes, the link above answered my previous question and it evolved into this. Thanks for reminding just deleted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A predicate with a subquery like this should work

```
SUBQUERY(tasks, $t, $t.completed == nil).@count == 0
```

to find all people without incomplete tasks.

Comment: And that translates to SUBQUERY(tasks, $t, $t.completed == nil) > 0 for all people WITH incomplete tasks. Perfect, that was precisely what I was looking for, thank you my friend.